# Insert ID letters and change fonts and spaces in multiple plots in R

Tags: r, layout, plot

I have a "layout" problem to solve: I'm plotting four graphics at the same chart using `par(mfrow=c(2,2))`. Eaht I need is to identify each one with a, b, c and d letters to make the appropriate legend and put the 2nd line closer to the 1st. If possible I want to change the font to Calibri also. I have more than 200 graphics to make, thats why I need a script to do the task.

Just to make en exemple, this is what I already have:
[image: What I have]

This is what I need:

[image: What I need]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to ask three separate questions: I'll answer the first one

You can use `legend` to add an identifier to the bottom right of your plot:

```
legend("bottomright", "A", bg="black", text.col="white", adj=0.75)
```

Check out `?legend` for more options for making it look the way you want

For multiple plots, if you are using a `for` loop, you can loop over `LETTERS` to get the letters in order

Answer (score 3):

Concerning space between plots, you may play with the argument `mar` of `par`. For instance: `par(mfrow=c(2,2), mar=c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)`, the vector is actually c(bottom, left, top, right). I found this out of the documentation of `par`, you can find it following [1].

[1] https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html

Answer (score 2):

Building on the suggestion from @CactusWoman, here is a reproducible solution:

```
mat <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
layout(mat)
for (i in seq_len(4)) {
  plot(rnorm(50), rnorm(50), main = bquote(Plot ~ .(i)))
  legend("bottomright", LETTERS[i], bg = "black", 
         text.col = "white", adj = 0.75, cex = 0.75)
}
layout(1)
```

[image: Plot]

To change the fonts, you will likely want to use a package such as `library(extrafont)`. Then call `font_import()` (note: this will take a while...). After which, you should be able to add `family = "Calibri"` to the call to `plot()` -- that is,

```
plot(rnorm(50), rnorm(50), main = bquote(Plot ~ .(i)), family = "Calibri")
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error message when I tried to save the plot as pdf using the Calibri font:  `Error in pdf(file = mypath, family = "Calibri") :  
  unknown family 'Calibri'`

Comment: @JoséRicardo Provided that you have already called `font_import()` you will want to call `loadfonts(device = "pdf")` and then call `pdf()`. Otherwise, perhaps clarify the problem and issue and open a new question as it will be easier for others to help you.